# Upload Visual Studio 2013 edits to Azure WebSite through VS Online

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-web-app-service

I have set up my account on VS online, and it works fine with Visual Studio.
All my local edits, once I've checked them in, appear in VS online without any problem.

On the Azure platform I have linked the website to the team distribution of VS online, and it says that it should automatically update.

However, all changes made both in VS 2013 and in VS online do not appear on the website hosted on Azure.

I'm sure I am missing something, but I can't quite get what.
Do I need to "build" the code, even if it's a mere website?

Comment: For your web site running in Azure, do you see the deployments in the deployments tab (page) for your web site?

Comment: I'm not really sure actually, when I go to "Deployments" in the portal, I see this message " The team project is linked. Visual Studio Online will build and deploy your project to Windows Azure on your next check-in". Then beneath it gives me the project address and it says "What would you like to do next?
Check in from Visual Studio 2012
Check in from Visual Studio 2010 "